# 4 bit to Decimal Converter IC

Tags: arduino-mega, led, pins

im using arduino and im out of pins.

I need something like a decoder but the problem is that the decoders only change one output pin I.E. for 0011 the output will be 0001000000000000 what i need is to have the first outputs on I.E for 1000 the output will be 111111111000000000 i basically need to light up to 16leds and im out of pins so i was wondering is there is any IC that does this for me if i have 1111 it will output 16 ones.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use one (or more, daisy-chained) **shift register** for that.

It will normally take you 3 pins and provide 8 outputs, or 8n where n is the number of chained shift registers still using only 3 Arduino pins.

One example of a shift register that fits your situation is the **74HC595**.

On Arduino, you can use `shiftOut` function to help handle those ICs.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the MCP23017 an i2c 16 input/output port expander. ([datasheet](http://www.adafruit.com/datasheets/mcp23017.pdf))

It allows you to control 16 I/O pins via a simple I2C interface (only 2 pins needed).  And an [Arduino library](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit-MCP23017-Arduino-Library) exists for it.